# How to enter piecewise functions into Mathematica

Tags: syntax, piecewise

I'm trying to enter a piecewise function (named `eq30`) into *Mathematica*. However, it seems not to work. The expression I entered is

```
eq30 = gr[x] == Piecewise[{{x, x > 1}, {0, x <= 0}}]
```

But, when I try to plot the equation as...

```
Plot[eq30, {x, -5, 5}]
```

It gives me an empty coordinate plane. Also, the `eq30` doesn't turn blue, as do my other 29 equations when I enter them. Any advice?

Comment: You will find [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/3066) and its answers a great help in avoiding beginner errors like the one you are making here.

Comment: You can't plot equations with Plot. You should use [functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html) instead.

Answer (score 6):

You seem unfamiliar with *Mathematica* syntax.

```
gr[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x > 1}, {0, x <= 0}}];

Plot[gr[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

Note too that your function is not defined for $0 < x \leq 1$.  Is that really what you want?

It is also good programming style to order the elements in a `Piecewise` from low to high (left-to-right on the number line), i.e.,

```
Piecewise[{{0, x <= 0}, {x, x > 1}}]
```

Comment: I agree with you suggestions but think it is worth pointing out that `Piecewise` short circuits. So sometimes it is beneficial to sort the arguments such that the most common cases come first.

Comment: Also, to fully comply with the "number line" tip: one would want to express inequalities in terms of `<` or `<=`; so, `1 < x`.